# How to group a list in python?

Tags: python, list, tree

Here I got a list of string:

```
['2-3-1-*-*','2-3-*-*-*','2-1-*-*-*','1-4-3-*-*','2-3-2-*-*','2-1-3-*-*','1-1-*-*-*','2-3-1-1-*'];
```

I am trying to group this string into a structure like this:

```
--'2-3-*-*-*' 
   --'2-3-1-*-*'
      --'2-3-1-1-*'
   --'2-3-2-*-*'
--'2-1-*-*-*'
   --'2-1-3-*-*'
--'1-4-3-*-*'
--'1-1-*-*-*'
```

This is like tree structure. I am beginner in programming, so can someone give me a hint on how can I construct the tree-like structure and any suitable structure that I could use?

Comment: By structure, do you mean the formatting of visualization when the list is printed? You can try using `pprint.pprint(lst)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I am using d3.js to create the visualization part. I intend to create a multidimensional json file through any suitable structure that can represent this.

Comment: It is not necessary to create a structure that can hold this, my problem is that if I want to directly write this list into a json file, I am not sure how to write into the file as it should represent this kind of tree structure. I am not sure whether I have make my self fully understood. Sorry for my poor English

Comment: If you create a tree-like structure in Python, you can export it as JSON with ease. see `import json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = ['2-3-1-*-*','2-3-*-*-*','2-1-*-*-*','1-4-3-*-*','2-3-2-*-*','2-1-3-*-*','1-1-*-*-*','2-3-1-1-*']

def isSubElement(subelement, element):
    return (subelement != element) and all([(e1 == e2) or (e1 == "*" and e2 != "*") for e1, e2 in zip(element.split('-'), subelement.split('-'))])

def parseTree(elementList):
    if len(elementList) == 0:
        return {}
    elements = elementList[:]
    d = {}
    for element1 in elements:
        parent = True
        for element2 in elements:
            if isSubElement(element1, element2):
                parent = False
                break
        if parent:
            d[element1] = {}
    for element1 in d.keys():
        d[element1] = parseTree([element for element in elements if isSubElement(element, element1)])
    return d

print parseTree(s)
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
{'2-1-*-*-*': 
    {'2-1-3-*-*': 
        {}},  
'1-4-3-*-*': 
    {},  
'1-1-*-*-*': 
    {},  
'2-3-*-*-*': 
    {'2-3-1-*-*': 
        {'2-3-1-1-*': 
            {}}, 
    '2-3-2-*-*': 
        {}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is super helpful. Although it is not what I want exactly, but it is quite near. This is a pretty good hint for me. I will continue to modify this. Later I will post my own answer on this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you're using some js library to render it, save it as a nested `dict` so that it can be exported to a JSON without hassle.

```
def parser(items):
    nested_dicts = {}

    for item in items:
        nodes = item.split('-')
        current_dict = nested_dicts
        for n in nodes[:-1]:
            current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(n, {})

        last = nodes[-1]
        current_dict[last] = current_dict.get(last, 0) + 1

    return nested_dicts
```

sample output with provided data:

```
{
  "1": {
    "1": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": 1
        }
      }
    }, 
    "4": {
      "3": {
        "*": {
          "*": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "2": {
    "1": {
      "3": {
        "*": {
          "*": 1
        }
      }, 
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": 1
        }
      }
    }, 
    "3": {
      "1": {
        "1": {
          "*": 1
        }, 
        "*": {
          "*": 1
        }
      }, 
      "2": {
        "*": {
          "*": 1
        }
      }, 
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful to me. This is a good example on how to further group the list, which I may implement in the future stage. Thank you so much! :)